# css :not() selector is not working

Tags: css

How I'm using the :not() selector wrong here? I'm trying to select all elements except the `footer` element; I tried with referring to the `footer` element with its class `entry-footer` but still the same result:

```css
article.post .entry-wrapper :not(footer) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<article id="post-92" class="post-92 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
  <div id="post-92-thumbnail" class="thumbnail-wrapper" style="background-image:url(
     http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2016/07/featured-768x438.jpg
    )"></div>
  <div class="entry-wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header">
      <div class="category-link"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?cat=1" rel="category">Uncategorized</a>
      </div>
      <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=92" rel="bookmark">Article title</a></h2> 
      <div class="entry-meta">
      </div>
      <!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header>
    <!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="entry-content">
      <p>Excerpt</p>
    </div>
    <!-- .entry-content -->
    <footer class="entry-footer">
      <span>December 2, 2016 by <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?author=1">xp95</a></span>
    </footer>
    <!-- .entry-footer -->
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector actually *isn't* selecting the `footer` element, but it *is* selecting the `span` and `a` children of that element, and turning the text inside them red. The `:not` selector will only exclude single elements.

Try the direct child selector `>` to only select direct children of `.entry-wrapper`. You can combine two similar selectors to get the children of the other elements too.

```css
article.post .entry-wrapper > :not(footer),
article.post .entry-wrapper > :not(footer) *
{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<article id="post-92" class="post-92 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<div id="post-92-thumbnail" class="thumbnail-wrapper" style="background-image:url(
    http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2016/07/featured-768x438.jpg
)"></div>
<div class="entry-wrapper">
    <header class="entry-header">
    <div class="category-link"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?cat=1" rel="category">Uncategorized</a></div>
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=92" rel="bookmark">Article title</a></h2>  <div class="entry-meta">
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>Excerpt</p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <span>December 2, 2016 by <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?author=1">xp95</a></span>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Probably dont need the second selector as color propagate from parent to all children.

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe:

```
article.post .entry-wrapper *:not(.entry-footer)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators):

```css
article.post .entry-wrapper > :not(footer) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<article id="post-92" class="post-92 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
  <div class="entry-wrapper">
    
  <div>** All the text **</div><br />
    
  <footer class="entry-footer">
      This is :not() working in footer!<br />
      <span>December 2, 2016 by <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?author=1">xp95</a><br />
        :not() working within tags under footer.
      </span>
    </footer>
    <!-- .entry-footer -->
  </div>
</article>
```